# symfony3 fos user roles and radio button

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

I'm trying to customize the default/register of FOSUserBundle.
I want add roles with radio button, not checkbox button but a error when i set  **Multiple** to **false**.

I follow the symfony docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Owner' => 'ROLE_OWNER',
                    'Salesman' => 'ROLE_SALESMAN'
                ),
                'expanded'=> true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true
            ));
    }
}
```

**The error:**
Notice: Array to string conversion
500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

*the trace:*

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Notice: Array to string conversion
    at n/a
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php line 73

    at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList->Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\{closure}(array())
        in  line 

    at call_user_func(object(Closure), array())
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php line 158

    at Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList->getValuesForChoices(array(array()))
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php line 37

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToValueTransformer->transform(array())
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 1106

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->normToView(array())
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 352

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(array())
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php line 57

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(User), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php line 385

    at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(User))
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php line 62

    at FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController->registerAction(object(Request))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(RegistrationController), 'registerAction'), array(object(Request)))
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 4245

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/var/cache/dev/classes.php line 4200

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 168

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/web/app_dev.php line 28

    at require('/home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/web/app_dev.php')
        in /home/amaury/PhpstormProjects/backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php line 40

500 @ fos_user_registration_register
119 ms
11.1 MB
 1
 test
 6
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's a normal behaviour. FOS use an array to store roles and expect an array from your type model. For example the `ROLE_ADMIN` has `ROLE_USER` too. (roles defined in your security file)

Comment: If your application requirement is a single role for an user, why don't you use a non-mapped field for role and manually do `addRole` when form submits.